# Make a variable standard inside function

Tags: php

What I would like to do is use a variable from outside in a function without having to define it or make it global.

For example:

```
$resource = new Resource(); //This variable will have the same value (always)

function hello(){
  $tag = new Tag();
  $resource->tag()->save($tag);
}
```

I want to be able to use $resource inside the function without having to do

```
hello($resource);
```

or having to make it global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a closure:

```
$resource = new Resource();
$myfunction = function() use ($resource) {
  $tag = new Tag();
  $resource->tag()->save($tag);
};
```

To call the closure:

```
$myfunction();
```

Comment: Do I have to add $myfunction = ?

Comment: It can be any variablename, `$hello =` would also work

Comment: Cheers. working as intended now. You're a lifesaver ;)

Comment: I have another question for you. The code that you wrote, is it possible to call the function from within the function? such as call $myfunction inside $myfunction?